# Rename of DotNetNuke Modules from current DotNetNuke Modules projects

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-9

First, I am having a DotNetNuke module project with FormAndList and I upload extension package into my DotNetNuke portal. Next, I need to customize the features for FormAndList, I copy the whole project and rename it into FormAndList_Cust, I rebuild it and upload extension package into my DotNetNuke portal. It shown me the following warning due to duplicate of package even I rename of my customize project into FormAndList_Cust.

> Warning: You have selected to repair the installation of this package.
>   This will cause the files in the package to overwrite all files that
>   were previously installed.

Next, I realize that my .dnn file still FormAndList.dnn and I rename it into FormAndList_Cust.dnn. I rebuild my project in Visual Studio, it shown me the following error.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     Could not find file
>   'C:\Users\yoong.hon.chan\Desktop\NET_DNN\DNN.FormAndList_Tab\FormAndList.dnn'.    FormAndList_Tab

How I can rename of my customize modules with FormAndList_Cust from current FormAndList project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It have found my solution to solve this problem in Module.Package.targets file, change

The following is my sample code.

```
<Zip Files="@(OutputSource)" WorkingDirectory="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Package" ZipFileName="FormAndList_Cust_00.00.01_Source.$(Extension)" />
<Copy SourceFiles="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\FormAndList_Cust_00.00.01_Source.$(Extension)" DestinationFolder="packages/" />

<Delete Files="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\FormAndList_Cust_00.00.01_Install.$(Extension)" />
<Delete Files="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\FormAndList_Cust_00.00.01_Source.$(Extension)" />

<Delete Files="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Resources.Zip" />


<RemoveDir Directories ="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Package" />

<RemoveDir Directories ="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\ResourcesZip" />
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click on the Project in the Solution Explorer.
2. Choose Edit Project (this will unload the project)
3. In the CSPROJ file find formandlist.dnn, rename it (look to see if it is in multiple places)
4. Save your CSProj file.
5. Right click on the CSProj file in solution explorer and choose to Load it.

Comment: I know how to rename my visual studio project. I just don't know how to rename DotNetNuke Module Project.

Comment: You've done everything right, you just need to finish the process by following the steps I document in order to get that last part to compile.

Comment: It does not work I have found out my solution. It works for me.